# java: read from text file and make objects of it and add to collections and then sort

Tags: java

What i want to do is:

1. Create an Employee class having private fields as mentioned in any
   of the file.
2. Read the content from the files(there are 150 files) in the folder
   and create employee object for each file.
3. Store the Employee objects created in a Collection
4. Create methods which would sort the employee collection according to
   the different fields in ascending and descending order.

And my code for the 1st 3 lines is:

```
package com.fulcrum.emp;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestingColections {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        File folder = new File("D:\\employee files");
        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
        ArrayList<Employee> emp = null;
        int id = 0;
        String name = null;
        int age = 0;
        for (File file : listOfFiles) {

            try {
                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);

                String tokens = "";
                String[] newtokens = null;

                while (scanner.hasNext()) {

                    tokens = tokens.concat(scanner.nextLine()).concat(" ");

                    tokens = tokens.replace("=", "|");
                    newtokens = tokens.split("[|\\s]");

                }

                id = Integer.parseInt(newtokens[1]);
                name = (newtokens[3] + " " + newtokens[4]);
                age = Integer.parseInt(newtokens[6]);

                emp = new ArrayList<Employee>();

                emp.add(new Employee(id, name, age));

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }

}
```

My problem is instead of just `add(`) I tried to add object in a specified index using for loop but it gave `IndexOutOfBoundException`.
How can i do that?can anyone please help?
And also I want to sort those abjects according to different field.
Please guide me on that too.

Comment: You initialize `emp` in the middle of your loop, so each time you read a file, you destroy your work with the previous one.  Simply write `List<Employee> emp = new ArrayList<>();` near the top of `main`.  Better yet, don't do everything in `main`.  Flesh out your class with instance variables and methods, create one with `TestingCollections tc = new TestingCollections()`, and have `tc` do something.  Then, you can break up your work into smaller methods, and *test them*.  `TestingCollections` is a bad name too.

Comment: yeahh u r rite..its working now... :) its print all 150 employeess objects..but how do i sort according to different fields..please help me to solve that

Comment: Does `Employee` implement `Comparable`?  If so, you can call `Collections.sort(emp)`.  If not, or if you need to sort different ways at different times, create implementations of `Comparator<Employee>` and call `Collections.sort(emp, theComparator)`.  Look up those interfaces; you might need a comparator for `id`s and another for `name`s.  Try going through the Java Tutorial for practice.

Comment: If my Employee class implements Comparable then how to actually compare..i mean i have 150 employees..1st i want to compare it on the basis of id and then name and then age.

Comment: what would be the comparison code look like..?

Comment: my Employee class has 3 private fields emp_id,emp_name and age..and also constructor and getters setters as well as toString().

Comment: Edit your post and show what your attempt at making `Employee` implement `Comparable`, please.  You can leave out the getters and setters.

Answer (score 0):

Without a stack trace, it's impossible to know, but IndexOutOfBoundsException sounds likely on the following lines:

```
id = Integer.parseInt(newtokens[1]);
name = (newtokens[3] + " " + newtokens[4]);
age = Integer.parseInt(newtokens[6]);
```

You are trusting that newtokens has at least 7 elements.

`newtokens` gets set here

```
newtokens = tokens.split("[|\\s]");
```

Therefore, there likely exists at least one line in at least one input file where that regular expression produces less than 7 tokens.

Have you examined each line of each file to make sure it meets your expected format?

When parsing a file like this, I prefer to check those expectations first and then throw a meaningful exception to make troubleshooting easier.

```
if (newtokens.length < 7) {
    throw new Exception("Too few tokens on line " + lineNumber + " of file " + file.getAbsolutePath());
}
```

Comment: no thats not the problem..the problem was i was initializing emp in between.. but now it got resolved..now i want to sort those 150 emp objects in collection according to different field..please guide me for doing that.

Comment: If the Employee class implements Comparable and provides a way to sort itself, then call Collections.sort(emp).  If not, then call Collections.sort(emp, comparator) and pass in a comparator which knows how to sort Employee objects.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand what the problem was without a stack trace, but it might be this:
you can add to a specific index in an ArrayList, but only if this index exists.

if you have a list of size 2, you can add to index 0 or to index 1.

If your ArrayList doesn't have any members you can add only to index 0. Any attempt to add an unexistent index will result in the ArrayIndexOutOfBounds error that you got